# Choose the starting point of the Origin?

Tags: c++, grid

I was wondering if it was possible to move the starting point of the Origin to the bottom-left-corner of my grid.

This is the code I'm working with:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

char **createBoard(int n, int m); // Býr til tvívítt kvikt fylki og skilar því til baka
void initiaizeBoard(char **p, int n, int m); // Upphafsstillum allt með '.'
void printBoard(int n, int m, char **p); // Prentum út leikborðið


int main()
{
    int rows, columns;
    int xhnit;
    int yhnit;

    cin >> rows >> columns >> xhnit >> yhnit;


    char **board = createBoard(rows, columns);

    initiaizeBoard(board, rows, columns);

    board[xhnit][yhnit] = player;
    printBoard(rows, columns, board);

    return 0;
}

char **createBoard(int n, int m)
{
    char **p = new char*[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        p[i] = new char[m];
    }
    return p;
}

void initiaizeBoard(char **p, int n, int m)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
        {
            p[i][j] = '.';
        }
    }
}



void printBoard(int n, int m, char** p)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
        {
           cout << p[i][j];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

}
```

For the input "10 10 5 6" my output is as follows:

```
..........
..........
..........
..........
..........
......X...
..........
..........
..........
..........
```

The Origins is now set in the top left corner as you can see from the output. I've been searching on this site and the internet in general and I can't seem to figure this out.

Comment: use std::vector<std::string>(or std::array<> where possible) instead char**

Comment: Print the rows in the reverse order?

Comment: Do you just want the display to come out differently, or is this a prelude to some extra more mathematical things? BTW - get in a habit of pairing `new` with `delete`.

Comment: Yes, this is supposed to be a grid game of sorts. I want to move the 'X' up, down, left,right in the grid depending on user input, but I've only just started.

Comment: You could write a helper "row" function which changes 0 to n-1, 1 to n-2 etc, instead of using p[i]j] use the row function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can treat everything the same and simply print the rows in reverse order:

```
void printBoard(int n, int m, char** p) {
    for (int i = n-1; i > -1; i--) { // Print in reverse order!
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
           cout << p[i][j];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Here is a live example: http://ideone.com/GJVw8M

Answer (score 3):

In a way, top-left and bottom-left are just arbitrary distinctions before you print the array. The array elements don't really have a physical location before you assign them one. So, in order to move the origin you can just print the rows from first to last.

```
void printBoard(int n, int m, char** p)
{
    for (int i = n-1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
        {
           cout << p[i][j];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am probably misunderstanding the question but is it just the output display that needs to change?

```
void printBoard(int n, int m, char** p)
{
    for (int i = (n-1); i >=0; i--)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
        {
           cout << p[i][j];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

}
```